# Showing that Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem is false in case of Riemann integration.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

I was reading Tom Apostol book called "Mathematical Analysis" and I read this statement: the Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem is false in case of Riemann integration.

Here is the statement of LDCT:

> [image]

**My question is:**

Could someone give me an example that shows that LDCT is false in the case of Riemann integration, please?

Answer (score 11):

Every Riemann-integrable function is Lebesgue-integrable, so the only way in which the DCT could possibly fail for Riemann-integrable functions is in concluding that the limit function is Riemann-integrable. It is not too hard to cook up an example of a (dominated) sequence of Riemann-integrable functions whose limit is not Riemann-integrable:

Let $\{r_1,r_2,\dotsc,r_n,\dotsc\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. Consider the sequence of functions $f_n=1_{\{r_1,\dotsc,r_n\}}$ on $[0,1]$. Each $f_n$ has only finitely many discontinuities, so is Riemann-integrable. Furthermore, the sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ is obviously dominated by the constant $1$ function, which is Riemann-integrable. However, the sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ converges everywhere on $[0,1]$ to the function $1_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}$, which is a standard example of a non-Riemann-integrable function, hence the DCT fails.

Comment: in the second line "... is in concluding that the limit function is Riemann-integrable". Seems you're missing a 'not'.

Comment: I don't think so. The version of the DCT for Riemann-integrable function (if true) *would* state that the limit function is Riemann-integrable and that is the only part of the "DCT for Riemann-integrable functions" that could possibly be untrue without contradicting the normal DCT (and indeed, it is untrue).

Comment: seems I misinterpreted your statement, because for some reason I read it in a way which seemed to contradict what you wrote in your comment (which is exactly what I was thinking). (anyway your example is quick and easy to understand, which is why I had already upvoted it)

Answer (score 4):

A bounded function defined on a compact interval is Riemann integrable iff its set of discontinuities have Lebesgue measure zero. Let $P$ be the [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) with positive Lebesgue measure.

Construct a sequence $(f_{n})_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ on $[0, 1]$ such that $f_{n} = \max(0, \: 1 - n \cdot \text{dist}(x, P))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Each $f_{n}$ is continuous, and thus Riemann integrable, by the continuity of the $\text{max}$ and $\text{dist}$ functions.

By construction, $|f_{n}| \leq 1$ for each $n$. However, its pointwise limit is the indicator function $1_{P}$, which is not even Riemann integrable as its set of discontinuities is $P$.

Comment: +1, since I followed your $f_n$ example. However, I am not familiar with the claim in the first sentence "A function is Riemann integrable iff its set of discontinuities have Lebesgue measure zero."  I found a link that makes this claim under the additional assumption that $f$ is a bounded function on a compact interval $[a,b]$, Theorem 6-11 here: https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/Riemann-Lebesgue-Theorem.pdf

Comment: In retrospect, boundedness on a compact interval is needed, else there are obvious examples where the integral can be infinity.

Comment: @Michael Whoops, that's correct. Boundedness and compactness is assumed. I'll edit it in.